# lme4: Why did i get an incomplete result when trying a more complex GLMM?

Tags: lme4

I'm trying to do a GLMM on my data.
The data are values on a TIMEPOINTS dependent from different TREATMENTS.

I have five different TREATMENTS: Oh, C, 12C_Gl, 13C_Gl and 12+13C_Mt
I have six different TIMEPOINTS: 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8 days

These are my fixed effects.
My random effect are the replicates for the measurement.

When working with easier models just Treatments or just Timepoints i got a result for everything.
When working with a more complex model which includes Treatments and Timepoints i got a incomplete result

**Just treatments:**

```
df$Tr <- relevel(df$Tr, ref = "C")
ldfXTr <- lmer(X ~ Tr + (1|Replicate), data=df)


Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: `X` ~ Tr + (1 | Replicate)
   Data: df
REML criterion at convergence: 7.6256
Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Std.Dev.
 Replicate (Intercept) 0.0000  
 Residual              0.2352  
Number of obs: 169, groups:  Replicate, 3
Fixed Effects:
 (Intercept)      Tr12+13Mt     Tr12C_Gl      Tr13C_Gl   TrOh  
     2.02447      -0.14991      -0.04620      -0.03191    0.22153 
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK) ; 0 optimizer warnings; 1 lme4 warnings
```

```
summary (ldfXTr)

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: `X` ~ Tr + (1 | Replicate)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: 7.6

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.36885 -0.56772  0.06179  0.52899  2.79932 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Replicate (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
 Residual              0.05534  0.2352  
Number of obs: 169, groups:  Replicate, 3

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    2.02447    0.03587 164.00000  56.431   <2e-16 ***
Tr12+13Mt     -0.14991    0.05776 164.00000  -2.595   0.0103 *  
Tr12C_Gl      -0.04620    0.05017 164.00000  -0.921   0.3585    
Tr13C_Gl      -0.03191    0.05017 164.00000  -0.636   0.5256    
TrOh           0.22153    0.08623 164.00000   2.569   0.0111 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Tr12+1 Tr12C_ Tr13C_
Tr12+13Mt   -0.621                     
Tr12C_Gl    -0.715  0.444              
Tr13C_Gl    -0.715  0.444  0.511       
TrOh        -0.416  0.258  0.297  0.297
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

**Just Timepoints:**

```
df$Timepoint <- relevel(df$Timepoint, ref = "0")
ldfXTp <- lmer(`X` ~ Timepoint + (1|Replicate), data=df)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: `X` ~ Timepoint + (1 | Replicate)
   Data: df
REML criterion at convergence: -99.8336
Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Std.Dev.
 Replicate (Intercept) 0.0000  
 Residual              0.1678  
Number of obs: 169, groups:  Replicate, 3
Fixed Effects:
 (Intercept)  Timepoint0.5    Timepoint1    Timepoint2    Timepoint4    Timepoint8  
     2.24600      -0.16462      -0.05856      -0.12974      -0.51581      -0.38992  
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK) ; 0 optimizer warnings; 1 lme4 warnings
```

```
summary (ldfXTp)

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: `X` ~ Timepoint + (1 | Replicate)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: -99.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6422 -0.5974 -0.0005  0.5400  3.3772 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Replicate (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
 Residual              0.02816  0.1678  
Number of obs: 169, groups:  Replicate, 3

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    2.24600    0.05594 163.00000  40.152  < 2e-16 ***
Timepoint0.5  -0.16462    0.06490 163.00000  -2.536   0.0121 *  
Timepoint1    -0.05856    0.06459 163.00000  -0.907   0.3660    
Timepoint2    -0.12974    0.06272 163.00000  -2.069   0.0402 *  
Timepoint4    -0.51581    0.06254 163.00000  -8.248 5.13e-14 ***
Timepoint8    -0.38992    0.06254 163.00000  -6.235 3.73e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Tmp0.5 Tmpnt1 Tmpnt2 Tmpnt4
Timepont0.5 -0.862                            
Timepoint1  -0.866  0.746                     
Timepoint2  -0.892  0.769  0.772              
Timepoint4  -0.894  0.771  0.775  0.798       
Timepoint8  -0.894  0.771  0.775  0.798  0.800
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

In both models i have a result for everything.
But when i used a **more complex model**, i got some values missing.

```
df$Tr<- relevel(df$Tr, ref = "Oh")
df$Timepoint <- relevel(df$Timepoint, ref = "0")

lmerdf <- lmer(`X`~ Tr * Timepoint + (1|Replicate), data=df)

*fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so **dropping 11 columns** / coefficients boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')*

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: `X` ~ Tr * Timepoint + (1 | Replicate)
   Data: df
REML criterion at convergence: -145.2895
Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Std.Dev. 
 Replicate (Intercept) 4.206e-10
 Residual              1.298e-01
Number of obs: 169, groups:  Replicate, 3
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)          TrC            Tr12+13Mt           Tr12C_Gl           Tr13C_Gl  
 2.24600             -0.42900       -0.36189            -0.40611           -0.36267  

Timepoint0.5         Timepoint1     Timepoint2          Timepoint4         TrC:Timepoint0.5  
 0.23478              0.33211        0.15044            -0.17122            0.03497  

Tr12C_Gl:Timepoint0.5         TrC:Timepoint1    Tr12C_Gl:Timepoint1        TrC:Timepoint2     
-0.03478                      -0.11178                   0.13756            0.34381  
     
Tr12+13Mt:Timepoint2          Tr12C_Gl:Timepoint2         TrC:Timepoint4    Tr12+13Mt:Timepoint4     
-0.10789                      0.22467                     0.26300           0.10000                  

TrSum12C_Gl:Timepoint4 
-0.18167   
fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so **dropping 11 columns** / coefficients
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK) ; 0 optimizer warnings; 1 lme4 warnings
```

```
summary (lmerdf)

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: X ~ TrSum * Timepoint + (1 | Replicate)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: -145.3

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.14368 -0.44677 -0.04707  0.41511  2.86359 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Replicate (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
 Residual              0.01685  0.1298  
Number of obs: 169, groups:  Replicate, 3

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                2.24600    0.04327 150.00000  51.903  < 2e-16 ***
TrC                       -0.42900    0.06120 150.00000  -7.010 7.56e-11 ***
Tr12+13Mt                 -0.36189    0.06120 150.00000  -5.913 2.18e-08 ***
Tr12C_Gl                  -0.40611    0.06120 150.00000  -6.636 5.51e-10 ***
Tr13C_Gl                  -0.36267    0.06120 150.00000  -5.926 2.04e-08 ***
Timepoint0.5               0.23478    0.06120 150.00000   3.836 0.000183 ***
Timepoint1                 0.33211    0.06120 150.00000   5.427 2.25e-07 ***
Timepoint2                 0.15044    0.06120 150.00000   2.458 0.015096 *  
Timepoint4                -0.17122    0.06120 150.00000  -2.798 0.005820 ** 
TrC:Timepoint0.5           0.03497    0.08789 150.00000   0.398 0.691257    
Tr12C_Gl:Timepoint0.5     -0.03478    0.08655 150.00000  -0.402 0.688374    
TrC:Timepoint1            -0.11178    0.08655 150.00000  -1.292 0.198505    
Tr12C_Gl:Timepoint1        0.13756    0.08655 150.00000   1.589 0.114079    
TrC:Timepoint2             0.34381    0.08789 150.00000   3.912 0.000138 ***
Tr12+13Mt:Timepoint2      -0.10789    0.08655 150.00000  -1.247 0.214487    
Tr12C_Gl:Timepoint2        0.22467    0.08655 150.00000   2.596 0.010372 *  
TrC:Timepoint4             0.26300    0.08655 150.00000   3.039 0.002803 ** 
Tr12+13Mt:Timepoint4       0.10000    0.08655 150.00000   1.155 0.249744    
Tr12C_Gl:Timepoint4       -0.18167    0.08655 150.00000  -2.099 0.037486 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 19 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it

fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 11 columns / coefficients
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

Why am I missing all values for "13C_Gl:?" and "?:Timepoint 8"?
Annotation: Treatment "12+13C_Mt" is only used for Timepoint 2, 4 and 8.

Do you have any solution?

It's my first question here, i hope i structered my question correctly.